# how to intergrate swagger ui on vercel laravel app

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, vercel

I have deployed my laravel app on vercel and I'm using swagger for documenting my api.
Swagger is working well on my local server "http://localhost:8000/api/documentation"
I need this swagger to be online on vercel.  please help me the process.

I created a folder called "swagger" in public directory of my laravel app and placed the swagger-ui package files inside.

Created and added .vercel.json file with this content

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        { "src": "/api/index.php", "use": "vercel-php@0.6.0" },
        { "src": "/public/**", "use": "@vercel/static" }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(css|js|images)/(.*)",
            "dest": "public/$1/$2"
        },
        { 
            "src": "/swagger/(.*)", 
            "dest": "/public/swagger/$1" 
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api/index.php"
        }
    ],
    "env": {
        "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
        "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
        "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
        "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
        "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",

        "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
        "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
        "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie"
    }
}
```

Now when i check for swagger in the link "https://your-vercel-project.vercel.app/swagger", it gives me a 404 error, not found.

I expected it to give me the REST API details of swagger showing in my local server eg login, register, forgot password etc

Answer (score 0):

It worked by editing some files.

.versel.json file

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        { "src": "/api/index.php", "use": "vercel-php@0.6.0" },
        { "src": "/public/**", "use": "@vercel/static" }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(css|js|images)/(.*)",
            "dest": "public/$1/$2"
        },
        { 
            "src": "/swagger/(.*)", 
            "dest": "/public/swagger/$1" 
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api/index.php"
        }
    ],
    "env": {
        "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
        "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
        "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
        "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
        "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",
        "L5_SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS": "false",

        "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
        "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
        "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie"
    }
}
```

route/api

```
Route::get("/stuff", function() {
    return ["a" => 1];
});
```

config/swagger.php

```
'routes' => [
     'api' => 'documentation',
],
```

Swagger is now online with the laravel apis under vercel with this path https://your_url for_vercel.app/documentation